# Fluent NHibernate primary key constraint naming conventions

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, naming-conventions, primary-key, constraints

Is there any way to create a naming convention for my primary key constraints in Fluent NHibernate?

I know you can name foreign key constraints, but it does not appear possible to name the primary key constraint.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

James Gregory from FNH says...

> No, that's not supported through NHibernate, so we can't support it either.

http://groups.google.com/group/fluent-nhibernate/browse_thread/thread/9ea7155407d33772