# Primary Key Names in Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Is there a way in Fluent NHibernate (or possibly NHibernate in general) to tell it to generate the primary keys differently?  It creates the column name for the key fine, but the index/constraint gets weird generated names like:

`PK__Address__3214EC2725332734`

`PK__CreditCa__3214EC2756CA82C8`

etc.

I can use straight SQL to rename them but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a similar question to this:

[Fluent NHibernate primary key constraint naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358043/fluent-nhibernate-primary-key-constraint-naming-conventions)

It doesn't seem possible to do it because NHibernate itself doesn't support it.

(I was irked to find out).

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to name all constraints thus:

http://marcinobel.com/index.php/fluent-nhibernate-conventions-examples/

Hope this helps, I checked with some colleagues...

Comment: Primary key *constraint* names are the exception to this rule. NHibernate doesn't support it, therefore Fluent NHibernate doesn't either.

Comment: You should delete this answer since it is wrong and provide no additional value